# Implementing standard deviation function in mysql workbentch

Tags: mysql

Hello I am new to mysql and trying to create a simple function to calculate standard deviation of a given column as a parameter to this function. I have having problem creating a for loop and increment the var variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Stdev` (col varchar(10))
RETURNS decimal(8,5)
BEGIN
    SELECT @col := 
    SELECT @mean := AVG(col) FROM mytable ;
    simple_loop: loop
        BEGIN
        SELECT @var := POWER(@mean - (SELECT col FROM mytable),2); 


    SELECT @stdev := POWER(@var,0.5)
RETURN @stdev;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL already has a standard deviation function, [`stddev_pop`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_stddev-pop).

---

But if you really want to write it yourself...

While you *can* write a loop in SQL, that usually means you're doing it inefficiently. SQL is an engine for very efficiently iterating over large data sets. If you're doing the looping yourself, you're not taking advantage of SQL.

Following [the algorithm for standard deviation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-standard-deviation), we can build this query up as a series of subselects.

1. Take the mean.

   ```
   select avg(num) as mean
   from foo;
   ```
2. Compute the difference from the mean and square it.

   ```
   select pow(num - mean, 2) as sqdiff
   from foo,
   (select avg(num) as mean from foo) as mean;
   ```
3. Get the mean of the differences and take the square root.

   ```
   select pow(avg(sqdiff), 0.5) as stddev
   from (
       select pow(num - mean, 2) as sqdiff
       from foo,
       (select avg(num) as mean from foo) as mean
   ) as sqdiff
   ```

Comment: Yes but I have to implement it as a function to get better precision.

Comment: @Saurabh Could you explain that?

Comment: @Saurabh Whatever the reason, I've updated the answer with how to do stddev maually.

Comment: Basically trying to this bit of code in mysql loop for (0 to length of column): var = (mean - column[i])^2; var += var; end loop stdev = sqrt(var)

Comment: supposing foo to be the table and num to be the number from  the column?

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, `foo` is the table and `num` is the column you're taking the standard deviation of. The subselects are basically taking the place of your loops. Again, I'm not sure what you mean by wanting better precision. It will only be as precise as the `power` and `avg` functions which are as precise as the `stddev_pop`. You can't add precision after the fact.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be using decimals with decimal(5,2) with 5 as precision and 2 as scale.

Comment: @Saurabh There's no need to rewrite the entire function for that. Use [`cast`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) on the result of `stddev_pop`. `cast(stddev_pop(num) as decimal(5,2))`.